# mount with cifs: parameter to replace uid and gid by their names instead

Tags: linux, mount, samba, cifs

About Samba in Ubuntu, if in the server exists an user created for example with the `omicron` name with `uid=1003 gid=1003` and executed:

- `sudo smbpasswd -a omicron`

Then, if in the client is tried (multiple lines for presentation purposes):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.X/thenumbers 
                   /mnt/192.168.1.X/numbers 
                   -o username=omicron,rw
```

I am able to mount the expected remote directory into the client, but is **not** possible write something, for example `mkdir 777` - it appears *mkdir: cannot create directory '777': Permission denied*.

According with `man mount.cifs` indicates:

- `rw     mount read-write.`

**Question 1**

Why the `rw` parameter didn't work as expected?

If the directory is unmounted and again if in the client is tried (multiple lines for presentation purposes):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.X/thenumbers 
                   /mnt/192.168.1.X/numbers 
                   -o username=omicron,uid=####,gid=####
```

Where:

- `rw` does not appear  anymore
- `uid` **must** be the same than the server side, in this scenario omicron's uid `1003`
- `gid` is optional, but should be the same than the server side, in this scenario omicron's gid `1003`

I am able to mount the expected remote directory into the client and finally is possible write something, for example `mkdir 777`

**Question 2**

Why did `uid` worked over `rw`?

**Question 3**

Is there some parameter to avoid use `uid` and use the user's name instead? I mean

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.X/thenumbers 
                   /mnt/192.168.1.X/numbers 
                   -o username=omicron,P1=omicron,P2=omicron
```

I read the `man mount.cifs` but I couldn't find something that represents `P1` and `P2` to be replaced and applied in the command shown above.

Answer (score 0):

About the Question 3: according with `man mount.cifs`

is possible use `uid` and `gid` with the names theirselves

Therefore:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.X/thenumbers 
                   /mnt/192.168.1.X/numbers 
                   -o username=omicron,uid=omicron,gid=omicron
```